# Is it possible that H1N1 infected 60% of the population back in 2009 in a country?

Tags: influenza

Nowadays we are hearing Angela Merkel with a specialist and a doctor in United States claiming Covid-19 could infect betweeen 50-70% of the population. According to this [CDC FAQ](https://www.cdc.gov/flu/about/burden/faq.htm) flu infects between 3% to 15% of people each year. So I was wondering if recently we got any disease with such large contagious rate as claimed by Merkel, and yesterday in argentine television a doctor said they made a research in Argentina and they got to the conclusion that back in 2009 Influenza A H1N1 infected 60% of the argentine population but many of them didnt develop symptoms. Is this possible? 
Is it possible that H1N1 infected 60% of the population back in 2009 in a country? Is there any other data which could back this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is related with mine:

We will never know how many individuals have been infected, we can only count the cases that have been diagnosed and these are those who are died or have been hospitalized or have visited the doctor.

So it could be possible that 80 % of a population is infected but only 50% are diagnosed and as we had also a medial hype in 2009 it is really surprising that the spread trend of H1N1 2009 in Argentina was so low:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009_flu_pandemic_by_country

I don't know where from Merkel has her information ...